# Solve for Matrix E

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following matrices C and D are given as shown

$$
C= \begin{pmatrix} 
0.60&0.40&0.50\\0.20&0.30& 0.40\\
0.40&0.40&0.20\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
D = \begin{pmatrix} 
-320\\
440\\
-2200
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Solve for matrix E in the equation $E=CE+D$

I can’t quite figure out how to start this one. The first thing I did was to simply multiply the two, but I ended up with E being full of variables and incorrect. What would be a good starting point?

Comment: Start by moving $E$ to one side of the equation.

Comment: This is a "system of linear equations".  Have you studied that topic?

Comment: Yes, it was given in this format though.

Comment: If you had $y=zy+x$ in real numbers then your solution for $y$ would involve $y-zy=x$  and $(1-z)y=x$ and so would be $y=\frac{1}{1-z}x$.  You want the equivalent for matrices

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you need to isolate $E$. To do so, the simplest is to write the equation as $(I-C)E=D$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then you can left multiply by $(I-C)^{-1}$ and get the result:
$$E=(I-C)^{-1}D$$